# How does scsi multipath work?

Tags: linux, scsi, multipath

I don't understand a little.
(hypothetical situation)
I have a Supermicro server with Linux. A pci hba is inserted into it. In the hba, via sff-8644, a jbod with 90 ssd is connected. sff-8644, this is 4 sas. In order for the throughput to the jbad to be 48 Gbp/s, it is necessary to use multipath and send scsi requests to rundrobin to each sas 12 Gbp/s.

1. Where does this happen? And is it happening? Does the Linux scsi driver do this? Or do I need to configure it separately?
2. What if I add another sff-8644 to use 96 Gbps. Do I need to configure anything for rundrobin multipath?